# how to pass custom dto as rest api input using postman rest client

Tags: java, json, rest, api, spring-mvc

Here is my code ,I'm trying to pass the user details as a json input but I'm not able to receive the data in my rest api method. I"m getting all values as null,

this is my json request

```
{
    "userId" : "12345",
    "username" : "arun.ammasai",
    "createdBy" : "-2",
    "updatedBy" : "-2",
    "statusCd" : "New",
    "createdDate" : "2019-03-03",
    "updatedDate" : "2019-03-03"
}
```

====================================================================

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/JSON", "application/XML" })
private String registerUser(User user) {
    System.out.println(user.toString());
    return "User Created";
}
```

====================================================================

here is the response in Postman Client

Unexpected 'U'

Comment: Please post full postman request including headers

Comment: I'm using my localhost , and header contains application/JSON, application/XML

Comment: so you have header with name Content-Type and value application/JSON?

Answer (score 2):

Update your method signature with @RequestBody annotation. It will automatically deserialize  your json into java entity. Be carefull, names in json should be the same as parameters in User object and User object should have getters and setters. So your method should look like

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/JSON", "application/XML" })
        private String registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
            System.out.println(user.toString()); //What is the reason of doing toString of java Object? 
            //better to do System.out.println(user.getUsername())
            return "User Created";
    }
```